# Discord.py not importing (No module named 'mysql')

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

When I try to import discord, I get the error;

```
>>> import discord
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import discord
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .client import Client, AppInfo, ChannelPermissions
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 42, in <module>
    from .voice_client import VoiceClient
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/voice_client.py", line 43, in <module>
    import websockets
  File "/Users/user1/Documents/websockets.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
```

The details for my python version
`Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5050, Mar 21 2017, 01:21:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin`
Could there be a file overwriting mysql by any chance?

Comment: What is that `websockets.py` in your `Documents` folder?

Comment: Oh dang, I didn't read that! I automatically skipped it. I checked it and looked like a test project that never worked. I deleted it and everything works just fine, thanks :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a file I made called `websockets.py` was conflicting with the module. I deleted it and everything works fine.

Comment: thanks future me, went back to this question and fixed it again